# Add new column to ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have ag-grid containing columnDefs and data. Number of columns is not fixed, so can not define columnDefs in advance.

How to add new column (lets say in  first position, kind of unshift) in existing grid?

### header1 | header2

value1  | value2

Result should be:

### newcol1 | header1 | header2

newval1 | value1  | value2

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise check this link : http://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-api/index.php

You have a setColumnDefs function to change the definition of you columns.
If you need to change data you have a setRowsData too.

You might want to check this exemple that use a tool panel existing in the grid : 
http://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-tool-panel/index.php